# Format plain text to HTML markup

Tags: php, html, cakephp, format

I'm using cakephp for my web application. I have a database table where I store some writings that are saved in plain text. What can I do so I can get the text it gets itself formatted i html markup?

For example I have a text on the database like:

```
blablablabalbalblablablablablablablablabalbalbla.
otherotherotherotherotherother.
helloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworld.
```

But when I get it shows it like this:

```
blablablabalbalblablablablablablablablabalbalbla.otherotherotherotherotherother.helloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworld.
```

But I want it to go into the html like this:

```
<p>blablablabalbalblablablablablablablablabalbalbla.</p>
<p>otherotherotherotherotherother.</p>
<p>helloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworld.</p>
```

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: split the string on \n and add p tags to the start and end?

Comment: Ditto on Greg's comment.

Comment: Show us your `secret` code.

Comment: I've tried what Greg said, but every 'n' gets it like a '\n'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you just want to preserve line brakes, you could wrap your text into a <pre> tag

```
<pre>
blablablabalbalblablablablablablablablabalbalbla.
otherotherotherotherotherother.
helloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworld.
</pre>
```

otherwise use php replace functions like str_replace on the newline character.
eg:

```
$in = '
blablablabalbalblablablablablablablablabalbalbla.
otherotherotherotherotherother.
helloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworld.';

$out = '<p>'
$out .= str_replace("\n\r" , '</p><p>', $in);
$out .= '</p>';

echo $out;
```

Comment: With the <pre> tags I still keep the line brakes, and I've tried your other function, but it won't find any "\n\r" strings....

Comment: unfortunately \n and \r are not the same on different operating systems.

also: \n and \r need to be written inside double quotations "" not single ones ''.

have you tried using the "nl2br"-function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: I used only "\n" and it worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are - or will be - using Cake2.4, it has a new method to format your code accordingly:

```
echo $this->Text->autoParagraph($text);
```

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/8cb84e7aa71b09d1b91591513375b6e2ba4f31af/src/View/Helper/TextHelper.php#L296

Until then you can just copy this method into your own custom helper.

Note that your code would not be wrapped in `<p>` but in `<br>` tags!
Only with a second newline (prior to the last row) you will get another p tag:

```
blablablabalbalblablablablablablablablabalbalbla.
otherotherotherotherotherother.

helloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworld.
```

would become

```
<p>blablablabalbalblablablablablablablablabalbalbla.<br />
otherotherotherotherotherother.</p>
<p>helloworldhelloworldhelloworldhelloworld.</p>
```

That's kind of the standard. So you should probably stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to wanna look at using PHP's string functions. You will probably want to find a pattern or repeat occurance in the text you pull from the database to make changes to the string. In your example the periods might be a good starting point. Maybe look at strpos() function php and the str_replace() function more specifically and how they work.

I suggest trying to learn about the PHP string functions and then attempting to use them to solve your problem. If you have issues post what you have done and the trouble you are having and it will be easier for people to give you additional assistance.

Comment: Exactly! I can help too, if needed.